# User touches UIButton too many times iPhone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

If the user gets impatient and touches this button before the next view can load, I get nested view issues, why isn't this working? I assumed that turning the button BOOL enabled to no would fix it, but it doesn't.

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
    startButton.enabled = NO;
    [activity startAnimating];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    view.managedObjectContext = context;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I forgot to hook up the IBOutlet in IB, damn, stupid friday morning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That OP code should work. Ensure startButton is the correct button and connected in IB.

If the action is caused by the button you want to disable then `self.enabled = NO;` is more direct.

Comment: Yes, this should work. But he want this to shouldn't work :).

Comment: @beryllium I clarified that the question code should work, is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have the entire thing inside an if statement.

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
    if(variable == TRUE){
    [activity startAnimating];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    view.managedObjectContext = context;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
    }
}
```

And set your variable = to TRUE or FALSE whenever you need to.

Comment: if `variable` is BOOL then use `YES` or `NO`.

Comment: I just looked at the project I'm working on, I have several BOOL variables and they are set to TRUE or FALSE and they work fine...

Comment: they will work fine, but the right approach is to use YES/NO.